# Is there a flag to tell CascadeClassifier.detectMultiScale() to find only one face?

Tags: python-2.7, opencv3.0

I have a Halloween prop that will be using OpenCV (Version 3) on a Rasppberry 3 (with Python 2.7) to track trick-or-treaters.  I take the X-Y result of face detect and control a servo with that value.

Is there a flag I can use to tell CascadeClassifier.detectMultiScale() to find only one face, or is there a better method to find just one face?

My goal is to speed up the face detect because I only need the location of one face.  If there are four or five faces in the webcam capture, I only need the first face found.

Thanks,
Steve.

*Dangerous novice.*

Answer (score 0):

There is no flag to detect only one face, but you can set the other parameters to both detect fewer faces and make detection faster.

In

```
void CascadeClassifier::detectMultiScale(
    const Mat& image, 
    vector<Rect>& objects, 
    double scaleFactor,
    int minNeighbors, 
    int flags, 
    Size minSize,
    Size maxSize )
```

1. set minSize and maxSize to include the smallesty possible size range for faces captured by your webcam that you want detected.
2. reduce the size of the original image image to speed up the entire process